# Vuetify error message color is not showing

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

I currently have a login form that is using vuetify and vuelidate. Vuetify is used to create the form and display error messages, whereas vuelidate is used to validate user input. My problem is that the error messages are not displayed in red. Below are my codes and a screenshot of the login form

Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(Vuelidate)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Login.vue

```
<template>
  <!-- v-container is used to center the contents -->
  <v-container>
    <v-form>
      <v-flex xs12 sm10 md8 lg6>
        <v-text-field
          label="Full Name"
          v-model.trim="fullName"
          @input="$v.fullName.$touch()"
          :counter="10"
          :error-messages="fullNameErrors"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs12 sm10 md8 lg6>
        <v-text-field
          label="Email"
          v-model.trim="email"
          @input="$v.email.$touch()"
          :error-messages="emailErrors"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs12 sm10 md8 lg6>
        <v-text-field
          label="Password"
          v-model.trim="password"
          @input="$v.password.$touch()"
          :error-messages="passwordErrors"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
      <v-btn @click="submit">submit</v-btn>
      <v-btn @click="clear">clear</v-btn>
    </v-form>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { required, email, maxLength } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fullName: "",
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  },
  validations: {
    email: {
      required,
      email
    },
    password: {
      required
    },
    fullName: {
      required,
      maxLength: maxLength(10)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    fullNameErrors() {
      const errors = [];
      if (!this.$v.fullName.$dirty) return errors;
      !this.$v.fullName.maxLength &&
        errors.push("Name must be at most 10 characters long");
      !this.$v.fullName.required && errors.push("Name is required.");
      return errors;
    },
    emailErrors() {
      const errors = [];
      if (!this.$v.email.$dirty) return errors;
      !this.$v.email.email && errors.push("Must be valid e-mail");
      !this.$v.email.required && errors.push("E-mail is required");
      return errors;
    },
    passwordErrors() {
      const errors = [];
      if (!this.$v.password.$dirty) return errors;
      !this.$v.password.required && errors.push("Password is required");
      return errors;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.$v.$touch();
    },
    clear() {
      this.$v.$reset();
      this.fullName = "";
      this.email = "";
      this.password = "";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like its missing some CSS and font.
I am using the stylus import with no issues.

```
npm install roboto-fontface

npm install vuetify
```

---

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/src/stylus/main.styl'
import 'roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

Stylus requires extra npm plugins:

```
stylus
stylus-loader
vue-style-loader
```

> Further debugging, ensure all of your projects components are
>   encapsulated in a layout with the **v-app** tag, standard vue project with an App.vue file expects v-app tag inside its template.

App.vue:

```
<template>

  <v-app>

    <login />

  </v-app>

</template>
```

**v-app** produces the following wrapper div tags that are critical to styles being applied to content within:

```
<div data-app="true" class="application theme--light" id="app">
  <div class="application--wrap">
     code injects here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I installed the extra plugins and imported import 'vuetify/src/stylus/main.styl'. But it still does not work

Comment: I believe you are missing v-app tag in your Vue.app file, i updated my answer.